# Show $2\sin(x) + \cos(x) = x$ has three solutions. Using IVT.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation

> Show $2\sin(x) + \cos(x) = x$ has three solutions. Using IVT.

**Attempt:**

After drawing the function on a graph I could observe that there are three solutions. So my first idea was to use the same idea used in showing that there exists $x \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ such that $\cos(x) = x$.

Applying this idea over the interval $[0,\pi]$ and defining $f(x) = 2\sin(x) + \cos(x) - x$, we obtain $f(0) = 3$ and $f(\pi) = -(3 + \pi) < 0$. So by IVT there exists an $x \in [0,\pi]$ such that $2\sin(x) + \cos(x) = x$.

**Comment:**

So I tried to extend this to the negative side, but the same idea failed. I have two questions:

1) Is this the right approach to take and maybe my arithmetic is off?

2) I arbitrarily picked the interval $[0, \pi]$ because I had a feeling based on the trig identities, but how would I go about selecting intervals if I wasn't aware of this? There must be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intermediate Value Theorem can only show that you have *at least* three solutions. To show that there can be no more requires further work.

So, you were right to start with $f(x)$. I'm not sure what you did with your arithmetic or trig values. Let's make a little table:
\begin{matrix}
x & f(x) \\
\hline
-\pi & -1+\pi > 0 \\
-\pi/2 & -2+\pi/2 < 0 \\
0 & 1 > 0 \\
\pi & -1-\pi < 0
\end{matrix}
(I think your values for $0$ and $\pi$ were wrong. So it makes me suspect any computation you were doing! :P)
This shows three sign changes; hence, since $f$ is continuous, the IVT guarantees at least three zeroes.

Comment: Even though the question here didn't specifically ask for it, how would I go about showing that there are no more than three solutions? ......I'm suspecting perhaps using contradiction....Beyond that I can't see how to flush it out.

Comment: Examine the derivative $f'(x)$.  It probably helps to observe that $2 \sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{5} \sin (x+ \theta)$ where $\cos \theta = \frac {2}{\sqrt{5}}, \sin \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$.

Comment: Yes, you want to apply Rolle's Theorem. If $f$ had more than $3$ zeroes, $f'$ would have at least $3$ zeroes. Sadly, $f'$ has infinitely many zeroes, so this isn't going to work. You have to resort instead to basic estimates. For example, using what @RobertShore said, you can see that there can't be any zeroes with $|x|>\sqrt5$, and then apply Rolle's Theorem in the interval $[-\sqrt5,\sqrt5]$ to conclude that since $f'$ has only two zeroes in that interval, $f$ can have at most $3$ zeroes.

Comment: @TedShifrin By the way, I think $f(0)=1$, not $3$.

Comment: Oops. LOL. I didn't bother to check that one from the OP.